# process complicated conditional checks with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file like so:

```
<root>
    <node ID="1" />
    <node ID="2" />
    <node ID="3" />
    <node ID="4" />
    <node ID="5" />
    <node ID="6" />
    <node ID="7" get="1" />
    <node ID="8" get="1 & 3" />
    <node ID="9" get="(2 | 23) & 3" />
    <node ID="10" get="((2 | 3) & 1) & 15" />
</root>
```

Ignore the first 6 nodes for a second. My XSLT is processing nodes 7-10. **What I want to do is "process" the "get" as a formula to get true or false based on if a node exists and the formula.** `&` is `logical and` and `|` is `logical or`.

So for example:

- node 7 XSLT would return true since node 1 exists
- node 8 XLST would return true since both node 1 and node 3 exist
- node 9 would return true because node 2 and node 3 exists (even though node 23 does not because of the `or`
- node 10 would return false because node 15 does not exists

Is there anyway to do something like this with pure XSLT 1.0?

If it matters, I can modify the format of the `get` value if there is some other format that'll make it easier to do what I want.

What I assume needs to happen is I send the value of the `get` for each node that I want to check (7-10 in this case) to a function that would "process" the formula and return true or false.

Comment: You need to rethink your requirements before asking about programming:  The name of the `get` attribute suggests *retrieval* yet the use of boolean connectors suggests *logical evaluation*.  Which is it?  Your examples suggest retrieval yet deny the logical nature of `and` by treating it as a mere separator for items to retrieve; further, your examples ignore logical `or` -- how would you "get" `2 | 4` ?

Comment: The parameter name `get` can be anything. I just called it `get` for the sake of simplicity. The idea is that the XSLT is currently looking at node 7. It'll use the formula in the `get` parameter to retrieve nodes based on their ID value. I updated with an example for node 7 to give a better idea.

Comment: You still haven't specified how you would want to "get" `2 | 4` differently than `2 & 4`.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 (or 2.0) cannot evaluate a string as an expression, even if the string were in valid XPath syntax (unlike your strings). Some processors support `evaluate()` as an extension function. Without it, you would have to do this in two passes, where the first pass would generate an XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: That is what I am asking here. `2 | 4` means get the nodes with ID 2 OR 4. `2 & 4` means get the nodes with ID 2 AND 4 -- so if either doesn't exist it would get nothing.

Comment: How would you express "*get the nodes with ID 2 AND 4*" in XPath?

Comment: @michael.hor257k You raise a good point. I have modified my question to do more specifically what I need. I need to basically check if those nodes exist...

Comment: What I said in my first comment still applies. if you want to evaluate these strings as Boolean expressions, you must either have an `evaluate()` function or generate an interim XSLT stylesheet where these strings will be XPath expressions - e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="boolean((node[@ID=1] or node[@ID=23]) and node[@ID=3])"/>`. -- Note also that your current input is not XML, as it contains unescaped `&` characters.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yeah, I did that for the sake of readability. And, yes, what I am asking here is how I would get/write that `evaluate()` function or the interim XSLT to do whatever is needed...

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: @michael.hor257k It's the one that comes with SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If it matters, I can modify the format of the `get` value if there is
>   some other format that'll make it easier to do what I want.

Well, if you reformat the `get` value so that:

1. a logical AND is written as `and`;
2. a logical OR is written as `or`;
3. each node is referred to as `node[@ID=N]`, instead of just its ID number,

so that your input XML would actually look like this:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <node ID="1" />
    <node ID="2" />
    <node ID="3" />
    <node ID="4" />
    <node ID="5" />
    <node ID="6" />
    <node ID="7" get="node[@ID=1]" />
    <node ID="8" get="node[@ID=1] and node[@ID=3]" />
    <node ID="9" get="(node[@ID=1] or node[@ID=23]) and node[@ID=3]" />
    <node ID="10" get="((node[@ID=2] or node[@ID=1]) and node[@ID=1]) and node[@ID=15]" />
</root>
```

you can then apply the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <axsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
    <axsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <axsl:template match="/root">
        <output>
            <xsl:for-each select="node[@get]">
                <result ID="{@ID}">
                    <axsl:value-of select="boolean({@get})"/>
                </result>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </output>
    </axsl:template>
    </axsl:stylesheet>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to receive this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<axsl:stylesheet xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <axsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <axsl:template match="/root">
      <output>
         <result ID="7">
            <axsl:value-of select="boolean(node[@ID=1])"/>
         </result>
         <result ID="8">
            <axsl:value-of select="boolean(node[@ID=1] and node[@ID=3])"/>
         </result>
         <result ID="9">
            <axsl:value-of select="boolean((node[@ID=1] or node[@ID=23]) and node[@ID=3])"/>
         </result>
         <result ID="10">
            <axsl:value-of select="boolean(((node[@ID=2] or node[@ID=1]) and node[@ID=1])and node[@ID=15])"/>
         </result>
      </output>
   </axsl:template>
</axsl:stylesheet>
```

This result is a valid XSLT stylesheet. Applying it to your input XML will produce the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <result ID="7">true</result>
   <result ID="8">true</result>
   <result ID="9">true</result>
   <result ID="10">false</result>
</output>
```

Comment: Well this is brilliant. Thank you so much!